# unable to deploy restful application liberty profile 8.2

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to deploy the RESTful webservices on liberty profile 8.5.5.2. I have enabled the `jaxrs-1.1` feature in server and I am using Java 1.7. When I start the server it gives me following error:

```
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
                                                                                                               JAX-RS Servlet
                                                                                                               accessms
                                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wink/server/handlers/HandlersFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:275)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initHandlers(DeploymentConfiguration.java:456)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:169)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:129)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:395)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wink/server/handlers/HandlersFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:275)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initHandlers(DeploymentConfiguration.java:456)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:169)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:129)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    ... 1 more
```

Following is the entry in my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.RestfulResourceLoader</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>propertiesLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>mobilehandler.properties</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

What other configuration I need to do in order remove this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Liberty supports JAX-RS 1.1, so you dont need to provide servlet class, just use the following fragment in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

See also:

- [Configuring JAX-RS applications using JAX-RS 1.1 methods](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_configjaxrs11method.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-28-2-0-0&lang=en)

**UPDATE**

The `HandlersFactory` is from third party libraries, try to add the following classloader (in the `server.xml`) to your application to make library visible.

```
<webApplication... >
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party">
    </classloader>
</webApplication>
```

Comment: @Gas..Thanks for pointing to to link. But after changing the configuration, as soon as I add the "<param-name>propertiesLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>mobilehandler.properties</param-value>", it again gives me same error. Does it require any more configuration or any other feature to be enabled?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari check for answer update, you will need to add classloader to the configuration.

Comment: Since I was deploying my application I did it like, <application location="E:\wlp\usr\servers\myserver\apps\myear.ear" >
  <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api"></classloader>     
 </application>. But it still giving me same error.

Comment: Your apiTypeVisibility needs to include "third-party" - Gas has it in his answer update but it's missing from the snippet in your comment.