# Specify user handlers for JAX-RS when using annotation scanning

Tags: rest, annotations, jax-rs, websphere-liberty, apache-wink

How to specify user handlers for JAX-RS when using annotation scanning?

I am following [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_handlers_customss.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-37-3-0) and have created my custom handlers. I have annotated my Application subclass as:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
        public class RestfulResourceLoader extends Application {
}
```

so that I don't have to entry in web.xml file. What I am not able to find out is where to specify the property file which contains this entry:

```
wink.handlersFactoryClass=mobile.handler.MyCustomHandler
```

I am using **Liberty Profile 8.5.5.2** with **jaxrs-1.1** feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you can only define this via web.xml file. This is also the way WINk supported.  In your case, even if you have @ApplicationPath("rest") defined,you can also have a web.xml.

Comment: Can you point me to the link from where you got this information?

Comment: The page you linked in your question, and the wink docs here both instruct you to add the properties file location to your web.xml:
http://wink.apache.org/1.0/html/5.1%20Registration%20and%20Configuration.html

Also note that user handlers are wink-specific and aren't mentioned in the JAX-RS 1.1 spec.

Comment: @Azquelt As soon as I add the custom handler it gives me error. I have opened another thread for that. Do you have any idea about this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768058/unable-to-deploy-restful-application-liberty-profile-8-2/30768939?noredirect=1#comment49663591_30768939